# VSTS CI/CD definition as scripts

Tags: azure, continuous-integration, azure-devops, continuous-deployment

We are building a Microservices based architecture and we are having 50 odd CI and 50 odd CD pipelines. Is there a way to script the CI / CD Build and Release definitions? We want this to be a repeatable process and do not want to leave it to our DevOps engineer(s) as it is prone to errors. Please note that I am not talking about ARM (which is already being used by us). Is there a way to do the above?

Answer (score 3):

For builds, you can use YAML builds, which are currently in preview.

For releases, there's nothing equivalent yet.

You could always use the REST APIs to extract the build and release definitions as JSON, source control them, and then create a continuous delivery pipeline to update them when the definitions in source control change.

Comment: How do I create YAML builds...Also, the json export option that's available in the VSTS isn't working when we import - it isn't allowing me to edit/save the imported definition.

Comment: Check this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/pipelines/build/yaml?view=vsts

Comment: Could you add this answer over [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51181530/722393) (re:REST api, not YAML), so I can accept it?