# How to automate Build/Release definitions in TFS 2018?

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I wish to automate management of my Build/Release definitions, for easy backup/restore operations.

How can I do this in TFS 2018? I'm open to using either the REST API or the SDK, although I prefer the SDK whenever possible.

**--EDIT--**

This is for TFS, not VSTS

Comment: Possible duplicate of [VSTS CI/CD definition as scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51082826/vsts-ci-cd-definition-as-scripts)

Comment: @DanielMann—I'd sure like to know how you find those gems. I looked and looked before I posted this, but nothing showed up. Anyway, do you happen to know how to get that button back that lets me mark that one as the answer? I reconsidered after I made the above edit.

Answer (score 3):

In TFS 2018 and later versions, it supports export/import build/release definitions directly. Build/Release definitions are implemented internally as .json files, so you can see details on changes in the file’s history:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Check the following release note:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releasenotes/tfs2018-relnotes#buildimport

Or you can use TFS REST API to get build and release definitions:

- [TFS build definition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/vsts/build/definitions/get?view=vsts-rest-4.1)
- [TFS release definition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/vsts/release/definitions/get?view=vsts-rest-4.1)

---

Adding a screenshot of how to check build definition history:

[image]

Comment: Thank you, Cece. I'd been using that to get by, but I've recently been overtaken by complexities. I now have many build definitions that were imported like this, and maintaining them has become cumbersome. This also doesn't give me one-click restoration of my build/release environment in the event of data disaster. In other words, I need IaaS.

Comment: It's looking like I'm going to have to dust off the SDK. I'll be needing class inheritance and conditional logic to pull this off. The one-click restore capability is very important for this.

Comment: You could get a specific revision of a build definition with REST api: `GET https://{accountName}.visualstudio.com/{project}/_apis/build/definitions/{definitionId}?revision={revision}&api-version=4.1`. Check: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/vsts/build/definitions/get?view=vsts-rest-4.1

Comment: Thank you for asking, and you did a great job building a nice answer that I was able to upvote, but unfortunately it doesn't solve my problem. I don't know why it took me so long, but I've recently discovered Task Groups. This feature goes a long way toward providing what I need, but it still doesn't address the one-click restore issue.

Comment: What issue did you get now?

Comment: Thanks for sticking with me. I need to be able to restore my CI/CD environment just as easily as I push out an application build. Build and release creation should be fully automated.

Comment: Doesn't REST API meet your requirement?

Comment: In the way that going 'round Robin Hood's barn to find the door does. The SDK makes it a little bit easier, but not much. I think [YAML builds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51082826/vsts-ci-cd-definition-as-scripts#comment89250134_51084466) are what I need, but as noted releases aren't ready yet. In any case, YAML isn't available yet for TFS.

Comment: YAML build is not available in on-premise TFS now, REST API is the best option to achieve your requirement currently?

Comment: Yes, that's what I said ;-)